# How can I run a numpy function percentile() on a masked array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I try to retrieve percentiles from an array with NoData values. In my case the Nodata values are represented by -3.40282347e+38. I thought a masked array would exclude this values from further calculations. I succesfully create the masked array but for the np.percentile() function the mask has no effect.

```
>>> DataArray = np.array(data)
>>> DataArray

([[ value, value...]], dtype=float32)

>>> masked_data = ma.masked_where(DataArray < 0, DataArray)
>>> p5 = np.percentile(masked_data, 5)
>>> print p5

 -3.40282347e+38
```

Comment: Best use masked methods or np.ma functions.  Many np functions delegate to the methds but dont count on it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looking at the `np.percentile` code it is clear it does nothing special with masked arrays.

```
def percentile(a, q, axis=None, out=None,
               overwrite_input=False, interpolation='linear', keepdims=False):
    q = array(q, dtype=np.float64, copy=True)
    r, k = _ureduce(a, func=_percentile, q=q, axis=axis, out=out,
                    overwrite_input=overwrite_input,
                    interpolation=interpolation)
    if keepdims:
        if q.ndim == 0:
            return r.reshape(k)
        else:
            return r.reshape([len(q)] + k)
    else:
        return r
```

Where `_ureduce` and `_percentile` are internal functions defined in  `numpy/lib/function_base.py`.  So the real action is more complex.

Masked arrays have 2 strategies for using numpy functions.  One is to `fill` - replace the masked values with innocuous ones, for example 0 when doing sum, 1 when doing a product.  The other is to `compress` the data - that is, remove all masked values.

for example:

```
In [997]: data=np.arange(-5,10)
In [998]: mdata=np.ma.masked_where(data<0,data)

In [1001]: np.ma.filled(mdata,0)
Out[1001]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

In [1002]: np.ma.filled(mdata,1)
Out[1002]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

In [1008]: mdata.compressed()
Out[1008]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Which is going to give you the desired `percentile`?  Filling or compressing?  Or none.  You need to understand the concept of percentile well enough to know how it should apply in the case of your masked values.

Comment: Compressed() did the trick for me. Since I needed to fully exclude the NoData values before percentile calculation.

Answer (score 14):

If you fill your masked values as `np.nan`, you could then use [`np.nanpercentile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nanpercentile.html)

```
import numpy as np
data = np.arange(-5.5,10.5) # Note that you need a non-integer array to store NaN
mdata = np.ma.masked_where(data < 0, data)
mdata = np.ma.filled(mdata, np.nan)
np.nanpercentile(mdata, 50) # 50th percentile
```

Comment: This is certainly a convenient solution (e.g., it allows applying the percentiles over a particular `axis`, whereas simply calling `mdata.compressed()` does not), but I'm concerned that it's expensive.